# Facing DataTables Speed loading issue in IE

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, datatable, datatables

I am using angular js as my front end and c# as back end. I am using datatable plugin to show my datatables on my website. But speed of data loading is very slow if more than 500 records in table. what to do?

I have tried in other browser like chrome and firefox, speed is pretty ok then IE

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#detailstable').DataTable({
                scrollX: '50vh',
                scrollY: '50vh',
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                "lengthChange": false,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel'
                ]
            });
        });
```

Comment: `DataTable` is a heavy data structure, can you convert it in to  `List<T>`, which is much more lightweight, even more important point here is for you to figure out what's slow, which function call is really slow to optimize and enhance performance. Use chrome debugger to understand overall time break up, is server taking time or client, if server, then which call

Comment: You should check these https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables